# how to cope with content of variable height?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

On [this page](http://festivals.ie/), there's an image carousel (from Twitter Bootstrap) which shows a series of images and captions. All the images are the same height, but the element that contains the carousel caption will be a different height depending on the length of the caption text.

This becomes a problem when the browser width is narrow (e.g. when viewed on a mobile device), because the difference between the heights of the captions becomes more pronounced as the window gets narrower. If you make the browser about 450px wide and scroll down beneath the carousel, you'll notice that the content underneath the carousel jumps up/down each time the image in the carousel changes in order to accommodate the smaller/larger size of the new image's caption.

This makes it difficult to read any text below the carousel (on a small screen) because the content jumps up/down about every 5 seconds. Is there a solution to this problem other than putting the carousel at the very bottom of the page or disabling automatic cycling of the carousel images?

Answer (score 1):

I hope giving a min-height to the .carousel-caption div can work. If not, try giving exact height to it on small devices using media queries.

First way:

```
.carousel-caption {
  min-height: 300px !important;
}
```

Second way:

```
@media screen and max-width:xxxpx
{
.carousel-caption {
  height: 300px !important;
} 

}
```

This may have some empty space on the bottom for small paragraph, but there's no way out. This will atleast prevent it from being up-down.

Answer (score 0):

If you're saying the caption container needs to be adaptive to it's child elements (the amount of characters to be displayed) you can try what @Darshan suggests along with `overflow: hidden;` css attribute, or you could set the caption container to an absolute position within its relative parent.

For instance,

```
<div class="relative" style="position: relative">
    <div class="child" style="position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0;">
        <p> My text yadda yadda yadda... </p>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

Setting a parent container to `relative` resets the boundaries for its child elements and all child element positions will then be bound to the closest parent with the `relative` position.

In this way, the content would still be shown, but it would not drop down into the rest of the content on the page, as long as the relative parent did not have a height specification.